# Recursively delete files older than 2 years (with specific extension like .zip, .log etc)

Tags: python-3.7

I'm new to Python and want to write a script to recursively delete files in a directory which are older than 2 years and have a specific extension like .zip, .txt etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know this isn't GitHub but:*                                                           I spend quite some time trying to figure it out and I have to admit the answer isn't that obvious but I found it
eventually. I have no idea why I spent half an hour on this random program but I did.
Its lucky i'm using python 3.7 as well because I didn't see your tag on the bottom of the post. *[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ybBW.png) is a demo of me running what is titled The Program*

## Features

**- Deletes all files from directory and subdirectory**
**- Able to change the extension to whatever you want eg: txt, bat, png, jpg**
**- Lets you change the folder you want erased to what you want eg from your C drive to pictures**

## The Program

```
import glob,os,sys,re,datetime

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\") # ------> PLEASE CHANGE THIS TO PREVENT YOUR C DRIVE GETTING DESTROYED THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE
src = os.getcwd()#Scans src which must be set to the current working directory 
cn = 0
filedate = '2019'
clrd = 0
def random_function_name():
  print("No files match the given criteria!")
  return;

def find(path, *exts):
    dirs = [a[0] for a in os.walk(path)]
    f_filter = [d+e for d in dirs for e in exts]    
    return [f for files in [glob.iglob(files) for files in f_filter] for f in files]
print(src)
my_files = find(src,'\*py', '\*txt') #you can also add parameters like '\*txt', '\*jpg' ect
for f in my_files:
  cn += 1
  if filedate in datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(f)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d|%H:%M:%S'):
    print(' | CREATED:',datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(f)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d|%H:%M:%S'),'|', 'Folder:','[',os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(f)),']', 'File:', os.path.split(os.path.abspath(f))[1], ' Bytes:', os.stat(f).st_size)
    clrd += os.stat(f).st_size
  def delete():
    if cn != 0:
      x = str(input("Delete {} file(s)? >>> ".format(cn)))
      if x.lower() == 'yes':
        os.remove(f)
        print("You have cleared {} bytes of data".format(clrd))
        sys.exit()
      if x.lower() == 'no':
        print('Aborting...')
        sys.exit()
      if x != 'yes' or 'no':
        if x != '': 
          print("type yes or no")
          delete()
        else: delete()
    if cn == 0:
      print(str("No files to delete."))
      sys.exit()
              
delete()


if filedate not in datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(f)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d|%H:%M:%S'):
  sys.setrecursionlimit(2500)
random_function_name()
```

## On its own

This is for applying it to your own code

```
    import glob,os,sys,re,datetime
    
    os.chdir('C:\\Users')
    src = os.getcwd()

    def find(path, *exts):
        dirs = [a[0] for a in os.walk(path)]
        f_filter = [d+e for d in dirs for e in exts]    
        return [f for files in [glob.iglob(files) for files in f_filter] for f in files]

    my_files = find(src,'\*py', '\*txt') #to add extensions do \*extension 
    for f in my_files:
      if filedate in datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(f)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d|%H:%M:%S'):
        os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!